How can we URL-encode ASCII characters using Python?
I'm trying to encode normal ASCII characters in my code. Is there a way to achieve this with Python?
I've used:
encoded_first_char = urllib.parse.quote(first_char)

but this will not encode the no special char.

You prefer your URLs to be three times the necessary size?

You mean percent-encoding everything?
The argumentless encode() call here implies we want to encode UTF-8 bytes to the percent-encoded string; add 'ascii' if you really only want to encode 7-bit ASCII bytes (and raise an exception if the original string contains something else).
>>> "".join(f"%{c:02x}" for c in "Hellö world!".encode())
'%48%65%6c%6c%c3%b6%20%77%6f%72%6c%64%21'

Pasting that to a JavaScript console to prove it's decodable by a browser:
> decodeURI('%48%65%6c%6c%c3%b6%20%77%6f%72%6c%64%21')
'Hellö world!'

